# model.save in keras vgg16 just save weights without model architecture

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model

I created my model and saved by using **model.save** .

I then loaded it by using **tf.keras.modles.load_model** which loads the weights and architecture.

The vgg16 model just save the weights without model architecture

The message error is:

```
(ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 15 layers into a model with 0 layers.)
```

Also, what is the difference between

**model.save** and **tf.keras.saved_model.save**

Comment: `model.save()` and `tf.keras.saved_model.save_model()` are the same

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to save the VGG model?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue in older versions of Tensorflow or Keras. There are related issues in Github and Stackoverflow as well.

But this error is fixed in the latest stable version of `Tensorflow`, `2.1`.

Mentioned below is the simple working code example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
import tensorflow as tf

model = VGG16(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = (224,224,3))

model.save('model.h5')

loaded_model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

model.save('model')

loaded_model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
```

Mentioned below is the output when executed the commands, `loaded_model1` and `loaded_model2`.

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 150, 150, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 150, 150, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 150, 150, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 75, 75, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 75, 75, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 75, 75, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 37, 37, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 37, 37, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 18, 18, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 9, 9, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 9, 9, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 9, 9, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 9, 9, 512)         2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 4, 4, 512)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
```

If you are facing issues even after upgrading your Tensorflow Version to 2.1, please share the complete code as mentioned above. We can investigate it further.